# Undefined variable laravel controller/route

Tags: laravel, variables, controller, routes, undefined

I am trying to obtain data from my database and show it on my index page.

```
namespace Svcrs\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Svcrs\Models\Reservation;

class dashboardTest extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $reservations = Reservation::all();

        return view('dashboard\index', compact('reservation'));
    }

    ........
```

The function index must gather all the data.

Route: `Route::resource('dashboard/index', 'dashboardTestController@index');`

Index:

```
<div class="col-md-3 custom-new-card">
    <div class="card paper">
      <span style="color: green;">{{ $dashboardStats['amountOfPassengers'] }} <i class="material-icons pull-right">people</i></span>
      <div class="card-row-new head">

        {{ $reservations ['departure_id']}}

      </div>
      <hr style="border-color: green;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it seems to be a undefined variable, which means they don't link well together. Can't find the right path.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where is `dashboardStats` variable defined?

Comment: {{ $reservations ['departure_id']}}
Thats where the problem is about, sorry. Not dashboard stats

Comment: check the answer section

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues you have with the code, first one is you are using the wrong `/` notation for the view route and you are also sending an undefined variable called `$reservation`, I think you misspelled this and actually wanted to send `$reservations`, it should be:

```
view('dashboard.index', compact('reservations'))
```

Next issue is that you are using `undefined variable name: $dasboardStats` which you are not sending through controller into the view.

You are also treating `$reservations` inside the `view` as a single depth array, which is not correct, `$reservations` is a `Collection` object which needs to be iterated over in order to retrieve values you are looking for.

Also the name of your controller is wrong inside the `routes`

Answer (score 0):

you have assigned
`$reservations = Reservation::all();`         <= here is "reservations"

you return with
1) `return view('dashboard\index', compact('reservation'));` <= here is "reservation" it should be "reservations"

and in the blade template
2) `{{ $reservations ['departure_id']}}`

3) and yes also the `->all()` will give you multiple records so you can't use directly like, `$reservations ['departure_id']`

4) one more that is $dasboardStats is not sent from controller

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is incorrect `dashboardTestController` is the name you are calling and defined `dashboardTest` this

```
namespace Svcrs\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Svcrs\Models\Reservation;

class dashboardTestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $reservations = Reservation::all();

        return view('dashboard\index', compact('reservation'));
    }
```